# MIssing <p> from HellowWorld.ts in SharePoint Framework HelloWorld sample

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

In the SharePoint Framework Yeoman generated [HelloWorld WebPart](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/HelloWorld-WebPart) instructions scroll down to :-

Switch back to  HelloWorldWebPart.ts  file.

Once you added your properties to the web part props, you can now access the property in the same way you accessed the  description  property earlier:

`<p class="ms-font-l ms-fontColor-white">${this.properties.test2}</p>`

we do not add `<p class=.... for test, test1,test3`

Is this missing ??

Comment: i have no idea what you're on about or what your asking for?

Comment: HelloWorldWebPart isn't a part of the OOTB Sharepoint Webpart Library. Please explain more of this web part of yours... Thanks!

Comment: He is talking about SharePoint Framework web-parts (note the tag :-), and the sample webpart comes as part of the generated project - see https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/

Comment: @SPDoctor :-) The goal of the day is met. I learnt something new!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorials shows you how to access the properties and uses *test2* as an example. You can however, try the rest. The tutorials focusses on key tasks one by one and move on so we can get to the next one.